# HttpClient for C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

just starting to create an API to my a web application using the ASP.NET MVC4 Web API project template. http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

No problems with the API so far, but I was about to write a small C# app to test the API.

Almost all the sample I can find is using the a class called **HttpClient**.

Where can I find the **HttpClient** and how do I install it?

Answer (score 9):

Rather than using the build in HttpClient class of the .NET framework which has a lot of issues when dealing with StatusCodes that are different than the expected ones. I recommend using a library called **RestSharp**.

It has become .NET Http/Rest client of choice, you can get it here:   http://restsharp.org/

It is a very powerful library that is perfectly suited to do what you want.

Comment: OK, thanks for the suggestion, will check it out. What I like with the HttpClient is the easy Get, Post, Delete syntax.

Comment: RestSharp is build for accessing WebAPIs, so rest assured handling Get, Put, Delete, Post etc. is extremely easy. Also and that's a huge benefit for me is that it takes care of serialization/deserialization. This really cuts down the development effort to a minimum: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Comment: Out of curiosity, could you link to anywhere showing the statuscodes problem with httpclient in .net 4.5?

Comment: The is a totally new HttpClient in .NET 4.5 (which is still beta though), it's much better for dealing with WebApi's by now, but RestSharp has proven to be a very effective library for writing WebApi clients, so that's my recommendation for now

Answer (score 8):

It's on nuget, search for HttpClient

http://nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http

Answer (score 3):

Use `WebRequest` as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx)

```
        // Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
        Uri myUri =new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
        // Create a new request to the above mentioned URL. 
        WebRequest myWebRequest= WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        // Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
        WebResponse myWebResponse= myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

If its a REST interface use RestSharp but you would need XSD first.

Answer (score 1):

If the class is not available from your code, then you could download it from a NuGet package, like described in the article:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Introduction-to-HttpClient-4a2d9cee

or you can try to locate it inside the namespace: System.Net.Http

There is also an example for you wich should get you started!